# java - Apache CXF add signing certificate as BinarySecurityToken into WS-security header

Tags: java, wsdl, cxf, ws-security

I'm consuming WSDL and I need to sign the Timestamp and SOAP-body using my client certificate when making SOAP requests.

My signing-certificate has to be represented as BinarySecurityToken in the message and be included in SOAP header like this:

```
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" soap:mustUnderstand="true">
        <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs
.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="X509-15730854BE4465A46D14538884282111">MIIFO.......56Q==</wss
e:BinarySecurityToken>
        <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-1">
            <wsu:Created>2016-03-16T09:53:48.201Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2016-03-16T09:58:48.201Z</wsu:Expires>
        </wsu:Timestamp>
        .......
```

I'm using WSS4JOutInterceptor to customize my request, but can't find a way how to include my signing certificate into the request:

```
// for outgoing messages: Signature and Timestamp validation
        outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, WSHandlerConstants.SIGNATURE + " " + WSHandlerConstants.TIMESTAMP);
        outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.USER, "sss");
        outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_CLASS, ClientKeystorePasswordCallbackHandler.class.getName());
        outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_PROP_FILE, "client_sec.properties");
        outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_KEY_ID, "X509KeyIdentifier");
        outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIGNATURE_PARTS, "{}{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body;{}{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd}Timestamp}");
```

Can anyone suggest me how to do it?

Comment: As far as I can remember you should change the value of SIG_KEY_ID to `outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_KEY_ID, "DirectReference");`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, here as an answer as requested. :-)

As mentioned in my comment you should change the value of SIG_KEY_ID to outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_KEY_ID, "DirectReference");